# UICollectionViewReusableView Reload Only Section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an `UICollectionViewController` that displays Cells and 2 `UICollectionReusableViews` of type `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` called `UICollectionReusableViewNormalMode` and `UICollectionReusableViewEditMode`.

The `CollectionViewController` has two modes, normal and edit.

In normal mode we use `UICollectionReusableViewNormalMode` that just has a label that says the number of objects in the `UICollectionViewController`.

In edit mode we use `UICollectionReusableViewEditMode` that provides a "Delete All" button.

When we switch from Normal Mode to Edit Mode, we have to call reload on the section so that we can replace the Old `UICollectionReusableView` with the new one.

Unfortunately that forces all the cells to briefly "flash" on screen.  Is there a way to be able to reload the "section headers" only but not the rest of the cells under it using **UICollectionView**'s APIs?